# Why is a Windows partition mounted while Linux is in use?

Tags: linux-mint, windows, dual-boot, partition-table, systemd-mount

Since I haven't booted into Windows in over a month and use Linux frequently (without restarting except to boot back into Linux immediately), why did I discover it mounted?

If I hadn't been looking through my disks for used and free space I never would have even noticed.

Then again, recently I'd siphoned a portion of the Windows Partition to feed the Linux partition. That's the only interaction I've had with the Windows partition I've had in quite some time. I've also checked up on it twice since.

A little later, I notice that Windows was mounted while my Linux distro was running. Is this normal? I can't help but think that something else must be involved, but I truly haven't made any new installs or significant changes other than the Mint Kernal and other updates.

Linux is also my primary Operating system using the Grub for a boot menu and Windows far down the list.

Comment: Check `/etc/fstab` for mount during the startup. Also are you sure you haven't clicked on windows partition accidentally in your file manager?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. It is normal for every OS to mount all the partitions on its startup disk.

Comment: Why then, was it not shown to be mounted when I utilized gParted to move partitions around the first time and thereafter (until recently that is)?

Comment: Perhaps you unmounted it during the process of moving partitions, and hadn't restarted your computers since?

Comment: That's what I noticed this time around; the discrepancy between my prior experience and this one. I've restarted the device multiple times to reset RAM. I'd checked after moving the partitions around 3 times, the 3rd being when I wanted to increment more space once again. If they're supposed to be mounted as you say, then perhaps I'm in error however it wasn't mounted on install (during use) and after, when I wanted to create more space. A record of that much is noted on my account through a question I'd asked.

Comment: Then maybe I'm wrong, but that's the way it's been on every Linux/macOS/Windows system I've used.